# How can I get AWS AccountID In this Jenkinsfile step

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cloudformation

I am updating Clouddformation notificationARN and not able to get the account id in notification ARN. It's going to be dynamic so I don't want to hardcode it.

```html
@Library('github.com/releaseworks/jenkinslib') _

pipeline {
    environment {
        PWD = "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/${JOB_NAME}"
        AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = "us-east-1"
        AWS_MAX_ATTEMPTS = "10"
        AWS_RETRY_MODE = "standard"
    }
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(choices: ['dev-mar', 'dev', 'qa', 'qa-mar', 'uat', 'prod'], 
            description: 'Environment',
            name: "ENV")
        ...
        ...
        string (name: "AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID",
            defaultValue: "AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID",
            description: "Jenkins credential ID for git (i.e. tigoid-nonprod)")
        ...
    }  //ToDo: Add logic to tie groups of parameters together (i.e. if you pick dev, you get all of the dev params)

    stages {
        stage("Clean up from last build") {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
        stage("Upload CFN files and scripts to S3") {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "sed -i 's/BUILDID_PLACEHOLDER_VALUE/$BUILD_ID/g' ./infra/cfn/master.yml > /dev/null 2>&1"
                }
                withAWS(credentials: "${params.AWS_CREDENTIALS_ID}") {
                    s3Upload ( acl: 'Private', 
                        bucket: "${params.DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET_NAME}", 
                        file: './infra/cfn', 
                        path: "${params.ENV}/infra/")
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Update Cloudformation") {
            steps {
                    cfnUpdate (
                        stack: "tigo-cognito-${params.ENV}-master",
                        url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/${params.DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET_NAME}/${params.ENV}/infra/master.yml",
                        paramsFile: "./infra/params/${params.ENV}/cf-params-master.json",
                        timeoutInMinutes:90,
                        notificationARNs: ["arn:aws:sns:${AWS_REGION}:${accountId}:CW-Notifications"]
                    )
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using different AWS Parameters and I can't set it as static value as environments keep changing. What is the possible ways to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AWS credentials you can use `awscli` to get AcocuntID dynamically based on the used AWS credentials inside your Jenkins job

```
                script {
                    def ACCOUNT_ID = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account" --output text').trim()
                    env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNT_ID --> this will be stored as env variable
                }
```